# SQL - only display either weekend or weekday price depending on date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL statement returning information from the database about available dates.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   venue 
WHERE  NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME 
                    FROM   venue_booking 
                    WHERE  date_booked = '2016-01-17') 
       AND capacity > 150
```

The table has two columns, weekday price and weekend price. 
I only need to show one of them in the final output, depending on the date. 
E.G. if date is during the week, display the weekday price of that venue.

Comment: Are you familiar with `CASE WHEN ... END` constructs?

Comment: Can we see tha actual table? I'm finding this one hard to envisage :-(

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL Reference [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek):

> DAYOFWEEK(date)
>
> Returns the weekday index for date (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, …, 7 =
>   Saturday). These index values correspond to the ODBC standard.

You can use this function along with an `IF` or `CASE` to solve your problem.

```
SELECT `all_fields_other_than_price`, 
  CASE WHEN DAYOFWEEK('2016-01-17') IN (1,7) THEN v.weekend_price
  ELSE v.weekday_price
  END AS `VENUE_PRICE`
FROM venue v
WHERE name NOT IN(
  SELECT name FROM venue_booking WHERE date_booked = '2016-01-17') 
AND capacity > 150;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this ?

```
SELECT *, IF(dayofweek(NOW()) = 7, v.weekday_price, v.weekend_price) as final_price FROM venue v
WHERE name NOT IN(SELECT name FROM venue_booking WHERE date_booked = '2016-01-17') 
AND capacity > 150
```

**NOTE**

Change number `7` in `IF(dayofweek(NOW()) = 7` to your desired day number.

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
    Select CASE when DAYOFWEEK(booked_date)>1 and
    DAYOFWEEK(booked_date)< 7 then weekday_price
    ELSE weekend_price 
    END  as price
    From venue
WHERE NAME NOT IN (SELECT NAME FROM venue_booking WHERE date_booked = '2016-01-17') AND capacity > 150
```

Answer (score 0):

Repeating the same date more than one time in a query can be dangerous (in terms of keeping the query consistent).  In addition, I am not a fan of `NOT IN`, because it doesn't behave intuitively with `NULL` values.

So, you might consider:

```
SELECT v.*,
       (CASE WHEN dayofweek(thedate) IN (1, 7) then weekend_price
             ELSE weekday_price
        END) as price
FROM (SELECT date('2016-01-17') as thedate) params CROSS JOIN
     venue v LEFT JOIN
     venue_booking vb
     ON v.name = vb.name AND vb.date_booked = thedate
WHERE vb.name IS NULL AND
      v.capacity > 150
```